# ListenAndServeTLS runs locally - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority in docker

Tags: docker, go, ssl

I am using [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to generate a self-signed certificate and authority. When I use these files locally with `ListenAndServeTLS`, I can successfully connect with cURL. My host O/S is MacOS.

However, when trying to run this Go code in a docker container, I get the following error:

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Many [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969195/docker-container-running-golang-http-client-getting-error-certificate-signed-by) posts suggest that the problem is `ca-certificates` is not installed and that one should run: `apk add ca-certificates`. I have done this, and I still have the problem.

---

### Generate certificates

```
mkcert -cert-file ./cert.pem -key-file ./key.pem localhost
```

*This means the cert will be valid for the domain "localhost", accessible at https://localhost.*

### Load the cert and authority in Go

```
    // Load cert + key.
    cert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")

    // Load our CA. (Mkcert also generates this btw, check the docs).
    caCert, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("rootCA.pem")

    // Add our CA so it's considered an acceptable rootCA.
    rootCAs, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
    rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":1234",
        Handler: router,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
            RootCAs:      rootCAs,
        },
    }

    _ = server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
```

*This runs fine and works locally.*

### Put it in a docker container

```
ARG GO_VERSION=1.14

FROM golang:${GO_VERSION}-alpine AS builder

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates git curl

ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . /app

RUN go build -o ./bin/app .

FROM alpine AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /user/group /user/passwd /etc/

COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

COPY --from=builder /app/bin/app /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

### docker-compose file

```
    my-app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 1234:1234
```

When running the above container and connecting over TLS, I get the unknown authority error described above.

What am I missing?

Comment: Since Go has different algorithms for each OS on how to calculate `SystemCertPool()`, can you update the question to include the OS of your host system where the app successfully runs?

Comment: the issue is with the multi-stage `Dockerfile` build. I've update the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with your multi-stage `Dockerfile`. While you copy all the necessary artifacts (source, certs etc.) for the first-stage, the final stage you only copy the binary `bin/app`:

```
COPY --from=builder /app/bin/app /app
```

You need to also copy over the PEM files that are used during the service runtime:

```
COPY --from=builder \
    /app/cert.pem \
    /app/key.pem  \
    /app/rootCA.pem \
        /app/
```

### Error Checking

No matter how trivial an operation may appear *always* check for errors (and boolean returns):

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to load server key pairs: %v", err)
}

rootCAs, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to load system keychain: %v", err)
}

caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("rootCA.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to read CA trust file rootCA.pem: %v", err)
}

ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)
if !ok {
    log.Fatal("failed to load CA trust: bad PEM format?")
}

log.Fatalf(
    "server error: %v",  // e.g. "port in use" 
    server.ListenAndServeTLS("", ""),
)
```

rigid error-checking like this will catch Docker build issues like this very quickly.

Comment: Thanks Colm! It was the certs /facepalm. I didn't award the bounty in time though, so you only got 25 from "community", sorry :(

Comment: Happy to help @Jimbo . Actually once you accept the answer, that gives the full bounty - so we're all good :)

Comment: @JIimbo one other thing to note: if you're PKI needs are in closed system (i.e. all certs are signed by the `mkcert` package) - then all you need is the `rootCA.pem` trust. So you can remove the `x509.SystemCertPool` call and just use [x509.NewCertPool](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#NewCertPool). You can also remove the `ca-certificates` references from your Docker build, as your microservice will load all of its trust from `rootCA.pem`.