# Container fails to make network requests - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking

A container running behind a K8s service fails to make network requests with the error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

The container is an API that serves incoming requests and makes external network requests before responding, it's running in a local K8s cluster managed by Docker desktop. The third party API being called is failing the certificate validation and Im not using a proxy or VPN.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this helps someone else as there are many different discussions about this topic online.

The fix seems to be that when doing a multi stage docker build and using e.g. `FROM golang:alpine3.14 AS build` along with  `FROM scratch`, the root certificates are not copied into the image.

adding this to the Dockerfile after the `FROM scratch` line removes the error.

```
COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
```

This was found on this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979541/356387)